# How to prevent IE Filters from covering up background image

Tags: css, filter, background, overlap

The site is [here](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/list-of-cards/abyssal-warder-fire). When the button in the menu is clicked, Internet Explorer will hide the icons. This is not the behavior in other browsers. The icon is a background of `<a>` for it to be click-able. Is there a way to show the icon when clicked?

Is it possible, using only CSS, that when `<a>` is clicked the filter would be applied to `<li>`?

This way, `<a>`'s background icon would be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem. Replace this code:

```html
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">
#menu li a:active {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='#476c2c', endColorstr='#ccff66')";
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='#476c2c', endColorstr='#ccff66');
    padding: 39px 0px 2px 0px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
</style><![EndIf]-->
```

With:

```html
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">
#menu li a:active {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='#476c2c', endColorstr='#ccff66') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_qvhVKLFln2A/TZ8U5OiFLlI/AAAAAAAAHqg/7OQqVItePoo/menu_icon.png')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='#476c2c', endColorstr='#ccff66') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_qvhVKLFln2A/TZ8U5OiFLlI/AAAAAAAAHqg/7OQqVItePoo/menu_icon.png');

    padding: 39px 0px 2px 0px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
</style><![EndIf]-->
```

You will get the same background image in every link. The solution to this is to just have separate images for every link: information, chat,...

Answer (score 2):

The reason why we see this bug, is because it draws the gradient over the icon, so as a temporary workaround, here is fix for IE. Where you have the last conditional tag, put the transparent color as the `endColorStr`.

```
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">
#menu li a:active {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='#476c2c', endColorstr='#000000ff')";
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='#476c2c', endColorstr='#000000ff');
    padding: 39px 0px 2px 0px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
</style><![EndIf]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Alex however, I changed the endcolor to 40ccff66 instead of just ccff66 so that it'll look better. The first two numbers are alpha colors.

Comment: ahh i see, didn't notice that.. i try not to use IE filters, so i'm not good with them hehe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting "a:active" or possibly "a:visited" with the same background?

[W3Schools CSS :active Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_active.asp)